# Make Tree data type instance of Show in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I am having trouble getting the following tree data type to print out in a way that shows the hierarchy of the tree:

```
data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
              | Leaf a

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Tree a b) where
         show t =
```

I can get the tree to print out its nodes in the correct order top to bottom, but I can't figure out how to make the show function keep track of how many spaces to add to a level to make it obvious that there is an actual *tree* structure being printed. I know I'm not giving much to go on with my instance definition, but I really just don't know where to begin since recursion is such a confusing thing to me right now.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't do this. `Show` is really for printing out things you can then copy and paste into your source code. You should probably write an independent function for this, or use a pretty-printing library.

Comment: Yeah recursion is confusing, perhaps using fold instead can be less confusing. S

Comment: You might like to peruse the source of [`drawTree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-Tree.html#drawTree), though it isn't annotated the way I would expect an answer here to be.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use `Show` for this, then simply use an inner function that takes an extra arg:

```hs
instance Show Tree where
  show x = show' 0 x
    where show' indent x = a ++ show' (indent+1) ++ b   -- or something
          a = ...
          b = ...
```

but I doubt you can draw a nice looking tree with just a single extra parameter — it seems like an altogether non-trivial task to print arbitrary trees using ASCII output. I think it takes significantly more elaboration.

You're probably better of reusing [drawTree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-Tree.html#drawTree) as suggested by Daniel Wagner, or something equivalent.